# Removing individual lines from text view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Is there any way to remove one line at a time from a text view using a button without clearing everything in the text view at once? I'm trying to have a button next to each line of text so I can remove any line and not just the previous line.

```
@IBAction func topaddbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = toptxtfield.text {
        if text == "" {
            return
        }
        txtview.text.append("\(text)\n")
        toptxtfield.text = ""
        toptxtfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 let arr = Array(txtview.text!.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropFirst()) 
 txtview.text = arr.joined(separator:"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let components = txtView.text!.split { $0.isNewline }
txtView.text = components.dropFirst().joined(separator: "\n")
```